# Why does this c program crashe?

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, pointers

I want to make a list of , for example `10` sentences that are entered through the keyboard. For getting a line I am using a function `getline()`. Can anybody explain why does this program crash upon entering the second line? Where is the mistake ?

```
#define LISTMAX 100
#define LINEMAX 100
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void getline(char *);
int main ()
{
    char w[LINEMAX], *list[LISTMAX];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        getline(w);
        strcpy(list[i], w);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%s\n", list[i]);
    return 0;
}

void getline(char *word)
{
    while((*word++ = getchar()) != '\n');
    *word = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Because `strcpy(list[i], w);` is copying data to an indeterminate target address. You never allocate memory for the target of your copy. `list[]` is full of indeterminate address values, and thus we walk into **undefined behavior**.

Comment: You might want to look at `strndup()`.

Comment: You might also want to look at passing a ceiling value to your `getline()`, or use the global `LINEMAX` and a counter. As written it will trip undefined behavior as soon as you enter a string of 100 chars or longer (including the newline).

Comment: @cdhowie: strndup() is not standard, so OP's mileage may vary.

Comment: @AndyG Depending on your definition of "standard."  It's part of POSIX 2008.

Comment: @cdhowie I thought it came in even before that. Wasn't it added in [IEEE Std 1003.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html) ?

Comment: @WhozCraig 1: You mean "IEEE Std 1003.1-2001", and 2: No. Your link is to the `strdup()` function, not the `strndup()` function. If you look [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strndup.html), you will see that POSIX.1-2008, (AKA IEEE Std 1003.1-2008) has both a `strdup()` function and a `strndup()` function.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson You're totally right, and yea, that would be later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string is a block of memory (an array), which contains `char`s, terminated by `'\0'`.  A `char *` is **not** a string; it's just a pointer to the first `char` in a string.

`strcpy` does **not** create a new string.  It just copies the data from one block of memory to another.  So your problem is: you haven't allocated a block of memory to hold the string.

I'll show you two solutions.  The first solution is: change the declaration of `list` so that the memory is already allocated.  If you do it this way, you can avoid using `strcpy`, so your code is simpler:

```
// no need for w
char list[10][LISTMAX];

// ...

// get the line straight into list
// no need to copy strings
getline(list[i]);
```

But if you want to stretch yourself, the second solution is to allocate the block of memory when you know you'll need it.  You need to do this a lot in C, so maybe now is a good time to learn this technique:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // include the malloc function

// ...

char w[LINEMAX], * list[LISTMAX]

// put this line between the getline and strcpy lines
list[i] = (char *) malloc((strlen(w) + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

This solution is more complicated, but you only allocate as much memory as you need for the string.  If the string is 10 characters long, you only request enough memory to hold 11 characters (10 characters + `'\0'`) from the system.  This is important if, say, you want to read in a file, and you've no idea how big the file will be.

By the way, why do you have `LINEMAX` and `LISTMAX` as separate constants?  Can you think of a reason why they might be different?  And why haven't you made `10` a constant?  Wouldn't this be better?

```
#define LINEMAX 100
#define NUMBER_OF_LINES 10

// ...

char list[NUMBER_OF_LINES][LINEMAX];

// ...

for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_LINES; i++)
```